# Using custom Js file for External Website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors

I am regular user of example.com (not mine) , They have some js file , which I need to replace with my local JS file which I modified to serve my needs. It's only for my personal use so I will handle the security.

I tried several methods for past 2 days, but it hasn't worked out yet. Right now this is what I do:

```
example.com
example.com/script.js
```

I am using xampp and edited hosts to load my script of `localhost/script.js` in the following way to prevent CORS:

```
test.example.com/script.js
```

And I use chrome extensions to redirect `example.com/script.js` to  `test.example.com/script.js`

Now I get this error

> Access to script at 'https://test.example.com.com/tv/vendor.js' (redirected from 'https://example.com/scrip.js') from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://test.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Can I fix this, or is there some other easy method to just show my local file instead of `example.com/script.js` in Chrome?

Comment: I know how to do this with a userscript, but it's a *quite different* method, are you interested in it? Or do you need to follow your current general method for other reasons?

Comment: Any method is fine , as long as it works for google chrome. I use tampermonkey.

Comment: Its in head tag

Answer (score 2):

One way this can be accomplished is with a userscript. First make sure the userscript runs at the very beginning of pageload: give it `@run-at document-start` *and* enable instant script injection in advanced Tampermonkey settings (if needed). Then, attach a MutationObserver to the document, which will run whenever a new node is inserted, while the page is loading. When the node containing the script tag you want to replace gets inserted, remove it, and replace it with your own.

For example, here on Stack Overflow, you can prevent jQuery (defined in its `<head>`) from loading with the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Replace Page Script Example
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  // Wait for the jQuery script tag to be inserted
  // It looks like:
  // <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  const script = document.querySelector('script[src$="jquery.min.js"]');
  if (!script) {
    return;
  }
  observer.disconnect();
  script.remove();
  console.log('jQuery removed');
  // Run your own code here
  // Inject another <script> tag if you want
})
  .observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

This results in `jQuery removed`, followed by a bunch of errors (showing that jQuery was removed successfully, since Stack Exchange's Javascript requires on jQuery to work)

To inject a script tag with your desired `src`, you can do:

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = src;
```

where the `src` variable is a string containing the desired URL.

When instant script injection isn't required to intercept the script tag you want to remove, you can also use a local file instead of an external `src`, eg use:

```
// @require      file://D:/myReplacedScript.js
```

where `myReplacedScript.js` assigns to a property of `window`:

```
window.runReplacedScript = () => {
  console.log('replaced script running');
};
```

and then, when the replaced script is found and removed, just  run `window.runReplacedScript()`.

Unfortunately, local file requires don't work in conjunction with instant script injection ([see issue on TM github](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/721)).

Comment: Hi  , its not working for link like  <script defer crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/main_chart.js" ></script>

it has been replaced by your code , but still web page runs code from original file.

Comment: Using those attributes works fine for me: see https://certainperformance.github.io/index.html using the userscript https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/7eff37615aebbbf801d2552b437947d4 , The page wants to load jQuery, but the userscript intercepts it and removes it, resulting in `$` being `undefined`, as desired

Comment: can you check https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE%3ARELIANCE, even though script tag is removed , site works fine , its loading the javascript  <script defer crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundles/main_chart.85ecd16351b3cf14818d.js" ></script>

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLeB5.png Make sure to enable instant script script injection, as described in the answer

Comment: Hi , I was checking the inspect element , js is served from serviceworker !! ?

Comment: Not for me, the built-in script never loads at all on my end